# Python: HTML regex not matching

Tags: python, html, regex

I have this code:

```
reg = re.search('<div class="col result_name">(.*)</div>', html)
print 'Value is', reg.group()
```

Where 'html' contains something like this:

```
        <div class="col result_name">
            <h4>Blah</h4>
            <p>
                blah
            </p>
        </div>
```

But it's not returning anything.

```
Value is
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 37, in <module>
    print 'Value is', reg.group()
```

Comment: ... and this is why you *should NOT* 'parse' HTML with regex.

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) then use the appropriate tools for parsing html.

Comment: @A A: no it isn't. <div><div></div></div> is.

Comment: @A A: No, that is why you should not 'parse' anything with regex without reading the `re` docs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use regex to parse html. Use a html parser

```
import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(your_html)
result = doc.xpath("//div[@class='col result_name']")
print result
```

Obligatory link:

[RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I'm getting results like this: [<Element div at 0xb72edc8c>, <Element div at 0xb72edcbc>

Comment: @Zeno: Yeah, those are all the divs lxml found in your html. The elements. You can print them, or do further parsing with them. For example, try this: `for onediv in result: print lxml.html.tostring(onediv, pretty_print=True)`

Comment: Does xpath support regex? I want to do something like (col|row) in there.

Answer (score 3):

The dot does not neccessarily match newlines in REs, you need the `DOTALL` flag `(?s)` for that.

Answer (score 2):

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html :

The special characters are:

'.'
    (Dot.) In the default mode, this matches any character *except a newline*. If the DOTALL flag has been specified, this matches any character including a newline.